# How to update table values automatically every day

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with the expiry date, if the expiry date is less than today's date I have to update the flag `IsExpired = 1`. I have tried with scheduling job, but it's not happening.

I have tried the following steps:

- I have created a stored procedure to update the column
- then I created a schedule that will run (execute the stored procedure) daily at 12:00 AM

Comment: Does your procedure works when you execute it manually?

Comment: So the job does not execute or is there an error during execution?

Comment: When i execute my procedure it's working fine, and i haven't got any error during creation of job schedule. @Amirreza Keshavarz,@peterSmith

Comment: so what is your problem exactly ? please make sure that the schedule is running

Comment: You're going to have to tell us more than "it's not happening".  If you've managed to successfully schedule a job (no error), and your procedure works, what _is_ (or not) happening?  Does the job (attempt to) run?  What happens when it does so - is there log output you can check?  Aside from that, what's wrong with just deriving the 'value' on-the-fly (especially because, as your table gets larger, the job won't complete in an instant)?

Comment: You need to look at the job history to see what the problem is.

Comment: I have checked in the job history as well , it showing status as Idle. And Last run outcome as Unknown.

Comment: I have restarted my sql server services and Sql Agent as well , now it's working fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view which populates its IsExpired column by checking the current date and the expiry date. You could then select from this view to know if a row has expired.

Comment: There is no issue with getting the Row which is expired.  But problem was , scheduling the job .  After restarting my sql server services and sql agent , it's working fine.

Comment: Mark your question as answered.

Comment: Accept your own answer. Click on the tick symbol below the downvote arrow of your answer. You must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the required authentication is correct. I mean (SQL Agent UserName ans Password).
 Restart the Sql Server Services and Sql Agent as well. Then start you job schedule.